# Handling the response from Google Speech

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have a speech-to-text app and I'm wandering a bit in the dark with how to efficiently handle the response and organize it to a transcription. I feed the transcriber function 45 second chunks like this: `all_text = pool.map(transcribe, enumerate(files))`. This is the response I get:

```
all text:  [{'idx': 0, 'text': ['users outnumber', ' future'], 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs', 'file_index': 0, 'words': [{'word': 'users', 'start_time': 0, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}, {'word': 'outnumber', 'start_time': 0, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}, {'word': 'future', 'start_time': 4, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}]}, 
{'idx': 1, 'text': ["and the sustainable energy'], 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs', 'file_index': 1, 'words': [{'word': 'and', 'start_time': 45, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}, {'word': 'the', 'start_time': 45, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}, {'word': 'sustainable', 'start_time': 45, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}, {'word': 'energy', 'start_time': 52, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}]}]
```

So here I had two 45 second chunks from Elon Musks speech. I cut most of the response to make it shorter, but as you can see, there are two chunks, with indexes 0 and 1. I'm wondering how can I get the transcription from this response based on the word starting_time value? Here I took only seconds but of course I can get nanos also. Is it ok to make another list to push all the words and then sort the list using the starting_time? That brings me into my second question: How efficient is this? If I finally have a mile long list of words and other info from multiple users, will there likely be some issues? Would there be some better way of doing this?

EDIT. This is what I tried. It works with short sessions, but the app crashes with longer ones. I wonder if it has something to do with the list getting too big?

```
words = []
clean_transcript = ''

for word in alternative.words:
    words.append({'word': word.word, 'start_time': word.start_time.seconds, 'participant': participant})

words.sort(key=lambda x: x['start_time'])
print('ALL WORDS: ', words)

for w in words:
    clean_transcript += w['word'] + ' '

print(clean_transcript)
```

Is there some obvious "don't do it like this"?

Comment: first try to do it with normal `for`-loop (or even with nested `for`-loops).

Comment: I didn't see all your data but it seems you have data already sorted by start_time so using `sort()` seems useless. I thought you rather need some filter which checks i.e `x['start_time'] == 45` or `x['start_time'] >= 45` but it would need `for`-loop, or list comprehension, or `filter()`

Comment: you can use list `clean_transcript = []` and `clean_transcript.append(w['word'])` and later convert to one string `clean_transcript = " ".join(clean_transcript)`

Comment: It's sorted when it comes from the transcriber yes, but when I've run for example ten audio files through that function, they are sorted by file at a time. And I wan them to be sorted by the time when all of them are ready, no matter from what file the data is coming. So in the final list I want the data to be in time order from all the the different files.

Comment: now `sort()` makes sense. Code looks OK - and it is more readable then list comprehension in my answer.

Comment: So there is no obvious performance issues or anything? Will need to go through my code again to see if something else is causing it not to go through with longer sessions.

Comment: code `" ".join(clean_transcript)` should bi faster then `clean_transcript += w['word'] + ' '` but difference should be seen only in very big data. Usually `print()` in loop makes better problem because displaying take long time and peole first remove `print()` or print less text (ie. only `.` dot to see if code still works) to make code faster. I would rather expect problems with sending and receiving data to/from Google Speach than with this part of code. With big data eventually  ou can keep it in `pandas.DataFrame` which use code created in C/C++ and it can work faster.

Answer (score 1):

First you should try to use normal `for`-loop or rather nested `for`-loops.

```
text = [
    {'idx': 0, 'text': ['users outnumber', ' future'], 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs', 'file_index': 0, 'words': [{'word': 'users', 'start_time': 0, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}, {'word': 'outnumber', 'start_time': 0, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}, {'word': 'future', 'start_time': 4, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}]}, 
    {'idx': 1, 'text': ['and the sustainable energy'], 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs', 'file_index': 1, 'words': [{'word': 'and', 'start_time': 45, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}, {'word': 'the', 'start_time': 45, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}, {'word': 'sustainable', 'start_time': 45, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}, {'word': 'energy', 'start_time': 52, 'participant': 'str_MIC_Ct3G_con_O6qn4m00bs'}]}
]

for item in text:
    print('---', item['idx'], '---')
    for word in item['words']:
        if word['start_time'] >= 45:
            print(word['start_time'], word['word'])
```

Result:

```
--- 0 ---
--- 1 ---
45 and
45 the
45 sustainable
52 energy
```

And later you can try to convert it to list comprehensions.

```
result = [[(word['start_time'], word['word'])  for word in item['words'] if word['start_time'] >= 45] for item in text]
print(result)
```

Result

```
[[], [(45, 'and'), (45, 'the'), (45, 'sustainable'), (52, 'energy')]]
```

Or without start_time

```
result = [[word['word'] for word in item['words'] if word['start_time'] >= 45] for item in text]
print(result)
```

Result

```
[[], ['and', 'the', 'sustainable', 'energy']]
```

Or if you want to create flat list instead of sublists

```
result = [word['word'] for item in text for word in item['words'] if word['start_time'] >= 45]
print(result)
```

Result

```
['and', 'the', 'sustainable', 'energy']
```

Comment: Thank you, will try that on my code. Could you check my edit also, there's an example how  I tried to solve my problem.